# How to show imageViews in RecyclerView (Android)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, adapter

I create a image's array : (logos.xml)

```
<integer-array name="icons"><Item>@drawable/pic_01 to @drawable/pic_04<item>
```

Then ,  in my class Function : I have

```
public Function(String name , int icon) { this.icon = icon }

public void getIcon() { return icon; }
```

Final , in FunctionAdapter , I get Imageview

```
punlic FunctionAdapter(Context context) { icons = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.icons);
```

my question is in onBindViewHolde(@NonNull FunViewHolder holder, int position)

```
 holder.itemImageView.setImageResource(icons[position])
```

is not working , I want to know what am I miss ? Thanks Help.

[I want to change my ImageView (pic1 to pic4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUqde.png)

my Adapter :

```
public class FunctionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FunctionAdapter.FunViewHolder>
{
   private final String[] functions;
   private final int[] icons;
   Context context;

   public FunctionAdapter(Context context){
       this.context = context;
       functions  = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.functions);
       icons = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.icons);
   }

  public FunViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {

  View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.group_layout, parent,false);
   return new FunViewHolder(view);
  }

  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FunViewHolder holder, int position) {

         holder.nameText.setText(functions[position]);
         holder.itemImageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
   }

  public int getItemCount() { return functions.length; }

  public class FunViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

   TextView nameText;
   ImageView itemImageView;
   public FunViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
     super(itemView);
      nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_title);
      itemImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_logo);
    }
}
```

Update :

my mistake , logos.xml maybe the problem , but I don't know Why?

I decide to edit my icons :

```
private final int[] icons = new int[]{R.drawable.pic_01, R.drawable.pic_02, R.drawable.pic_03, R.drawable.pic_04} ;
```

then , pics will change.

Comment: can you add the error?

Comment: @ Anjani Mittal , the error is no imageView show in RecyclerView .

Comment: can you post the whole adapter class

Comment: use Picasso library to set image

Answer (score 0):

you have to use String[] instead of String on constructor.

use

```
public Function(String[] name , int icon) { this.icon = icon }
```

instead of

```
public Function(String name , int icon) { this.icon = icon }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **setImageDrawable()** method to load local drawables instead of using setImageResource.

```
holder.itemImageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(icons[position]))
```

Comment: Then use context.getResources().getDrawable()

Comment: I get "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 "

Comment: Then your @drawable/pic_01 is not in drawable folder which you mentioned in logos.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code 

 private int[] confirmIcon = {R.drawable.ic_action_green, 
                              R.drawable.ic_action_yellow, 
                              R.drawable.ic_action_red};



 switch ("your condition") {
            case 0:
                holder.ivConfirm.setImageResource(confirmIcon[0]);
                break;
            case 1:
                holder.ivConfirm.setImageResource(confirmIcon[1]);
                break;
            case 2:
                holder.ivConfirm.setImageResource(confirmIcon[2]);
                break;


        }
```